# Why the indexonly attribute value is false from mongodb explain query output

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple collection named `customers`  as shown below

```
 db.customers.find().pretty()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("524eb09ca71b72672e65ebb6"),
        "name" : "kiran",
        "occupation" : "SelfEmployeed",
        "country" : "IND"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("524eb0a4a71b72672e65ebb7"),
        "name" : "Mark",
        "occupation" : "Architect",
        "country" : "US"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("524eb0aba71b72672e65ebb8"),
        "name" : "beast",
        "occupation" : "housewife",
        "country" : "UK"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("524eb0b2a71b72672e65ebb9"),
        "name" : "Philip",
        "occupation" : "Engineer",
        "country" : "SWE"
}
```

I have created indexes on the name and country fields as shown below

```
 db.customers.ensureIndex({name : 1}, {"unique" : false})



db.customers.ensureIndex({country : 1}, {"unique" : false})
```

The indexes have been created

```
 db.customers.getIndexKeys()
```

**[ { "_id" : 1 }, { "name" : 1 }, { "country" : 1 } ]**

This was the result of my query explain

```
db.customers.find({name : "Mark"}).explain()

{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "name" : [
                        [
                                "Mark",
                                "Mark"
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "************"
}
```

**Why the indexonly attribute value is false ??**

I have seen similar question which explains it is due to

indexonly is false as  It wont use index only because you'll be retrieving other fields via that query that aren't indexed.

Please let me know what does other fields mean here ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some searching would have actually have got you a question I answered some time ago on this very subject.

The reason is this:

```
db.customers.find({name : "Mark"}).explain()
```

There is no projection, how can MongoDB know that the index covers the return without looking at the actual documents in this case?

It is similar to

```
SELECT * from customers
```

And

```
SELECT d from customers
```

How can you know `*` is `d` without looking?

Comment: Thanks , So the indexOnly would be false for every query in the world ?? Is there any case that it would have value true for any case ??

Comment: @PreethiJain If you add some fields for projection

Comment: @PreethiJain Try `db.customers.find({name : "Mark"}, {name : 1, _id: 0}).explain()`, it should be `indexOnly: true`.